# sunspot solr NGramFilterFactory not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails','3.2.17'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
sunspot (2.1.0)
  pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
  rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
sunspot_matchers (2.1.0.1)
sunspot_rails (2.1.0)
  nokogiri
  rails (>= 3)
  sunspot (= 2.1.0)
sunspot_solr (2.1.0)
therubyracer (0.12.1)
  libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
  ref
```

schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here is [solrconfig.xml](https://gist.github.com/swatijadhav/18678872c0c3e3be64ff#file-solrconfig-xml)

I have above settings in my rails application, solr-reindex completes without any error.
When i try to search for full-word, it fetches proper results but the substring-search does not work.
Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to use NGramFilterFactory and not EdgeNGramFilterFactory ? Can you show searchable block and an example of search which is not working ?

Comment: Yes, i want substring search and hence using NGramFilterFactory
For ex. searching "ell" should fetch "Hello".
Currently it only works for full-word search.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented solr search for single character but the same can be done for any number of characters.

Step 1. rake sunspot:solr:stop

Step 2. Edit the solr/conf/schema.xml file;

`## This you have already done by setting minGramSize="2"`

Step 3. rake sunspot:solr:start

Step 4. rake sunspot:reindex

Comment: I have followed same steps as you have mentioned, but still its not working for me. I have done implemented solr substring search before in other rails application with old versions of sunspot gem.

Here it might be some conflict with gem version, but not sure.

Comment: After fourth step, you need to restart you rails server.

Comment: Can you join the chat room. I can send you some code, so that you can try it.